# Dynamically assign templateUrl in angular component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-components

I have an angular component I am building in angular 1.5.  It looks like this:

```
var module = angular.module("ncRelationshipSearch");

module.component("relationshipSearch", {
    templateUrl: <need to dynamically assign>,
    controllerAs: "vm",
    controller: ['config', function(config){
         ... config provider here knows about templateURL...
    }
}
```

I need the templateUrl to be assignable somehow.  I have a `config` provider that could supply the URL but I can't inject it at the point of component definition.  Is there a way to get the URL in through the bindings or set it later in the controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have function for `templateUrl` where you can inject `service/factory`. You can actually inject `config` provider over the `templateUrl` function.

```
module.component("relationshipSearch", {
    templateUrl: function(config){
       //play here with service variables generate templateUrl
       //other code can also lie here. :)
       return config.myTemplatUrl;
    },
    controllerAs: "vm",
    controller: ['config', function(config){
         ... config provider here knows about templateURL...
    }
}
```